# A definition in Character theory?

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I would like to know the meaning of the term Character Field used by B. Huppert in his book Endliche Gruppen 1. For example they have used the notation $K(\chi)$. I dont know what it stands for?

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing all the values taken by $\chi$.  I'd imagine it would be defined in the text though.